# Fill images on listView space in Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, imagelist

Is it possible to fill up images on listView space instead of each taking up a separate line in listView.
I have a imageList object which stored all the required image and want it to fill up the spaces in listView. I have added imageList object to smallImageList property and changed View property to smallIcon in drag and drop design page. Used below line to display the listView.
`listView1.Items.Add("",0);
 listView1.Items.Add("", 1);
 listView1.Items.Add("", 2);
 listView1.Items.Add("", 4);`

Thanks

Comment: @Bahrom Thanks for the suggestions, that worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that with ListView control. Instead I suggest to use FlowLayoutPanel. You can add PictureBoxes on it setting them same size.